# Gráficar 2 categorías(consultas) con JSON en Highcharts

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, highcharts

Quiero poder gráficar dos categorías de unos datos de MySql, es decir con dos consultas, una que me diga el monto de dinero que se vendió en total y la otra
que me diga cuantos productos se vendieron ese día. Vale aclarar que con una consulta funciona, es decir gráfica, pero intente muy ingenuamente con dos y no se declarar sintaxis para esta situación.

El código que tengo es el siguiente:

**HTML**

```
<script src="../hw/Highcharts/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../hw/Highcharts/js/jquery.js"></script>

<div class="caja">
    <select name="ANO" id="ANO" autofocus="autofocus">
      <option>Seleccione...</option>
      <option value="2017">2017</option>
      <option value="2018">2018</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="caja">
    <select name="MES" id="MES">
      <option>Seleccione...</option>
      <option value="01">ENERO</option>
      <option value="02">FEBRERO</option>
      <option value="03">MARZO</option>
      <option value="04">ABRIL</option>
      <option value="05">MAYO</option>
      <option value="06">JUNIO</option>
      <option value="07">JULIO</option>
      <option value="08">AGOSTO</option>
      <option value="09">SEPTIEMBRE</option>
      <option value="10">OCTUBRE</option>
      <option value="11">NOVIEMBRE</option>
      <option value="12">DICIEMBRE</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>

jQuery(function ($) {
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
      renderTo: 'container'
  },

  series: [{
    name : "Ventas",
    data: []
    },{
    name : "Genero M",
    data: []
    }
    ]
  });

  $( "#MES" ).change(function() {
     //validamos las fechass
    var ANO = $('#ANO').val();
    var MES = $('#MES').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "procesar.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: { ANO: ANO, MES: MES },
      dataType: "json"
    })

   .done(function(data) {

   console.log(data);
   console.log(ANO);
   console.log(MES);
   //No se como colocar la sintaxis para los chart.series cuando es mas de 
   uno     
   chart.series[0].setData(data);
   chart.series[1].setData(data2);

    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Ingenuamente quise llamar los datos de esta forma en la consulta, obviamente no esta bien, pues no gráfica.

**PHP**

```
<?php require_once('../../Connections/conexion.php'); ?>

<?php

$MES = $_POST['MES']; 
$ANO = $_POST['ANO']; 
$resultado = [];
$resultado2 = [];

for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; $i++) { 
$query= "SELECT SUM(monto_venta) AS r FROM pruebas WHERE 
DAY(fecha_venta)='$i' AND MONTH(fecha_venta)='$MES' AND YEAR(fecha_venta) = 
'$ANO'"; 

$result =  mysql_query($query, $conexion); 
$valor = mysql_result($result, 0); 
$resultado[] = round($valor, 1); 
}

for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; $i++) { 
$query2= "SELECT SUM(productos) AS prod FROM pruebas WHERE 
DAY(fecha_venta)='$i' AND MONTH(fecha_venta)='$MES' AND YEAR(fecha_venta) = 
'$ANO'"; 

$result2 =  mysql_query($query2, $conexion); 
$valor2 = mysql_result($result2, 0); 
$resultado2[] = round($valor2, 1); 
}  

echo json_encode($resultado);
echo json_encode($resultado2);

?>
```

Comment: 1) Mira la consola a ver si arroja errores. 2) intenta declarar dos elementos con id's diferentes que tendrán las gráficas. 3) *si no lo has hecho aún*, investiga. He leído varias preguntas en Stack Overflow en Español y Stack Overflow con problemas similares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si concatenas dos cadenas JSON no obtienes un JSON bien formado, que es lo que intentas hacer con las líneas:

```
echo json_encode($resultado);
echo json_encode($resultado2);
```

En su lugar debes generar un JSON a partir de una matriz cuyos elementos sean las dos matrices:

```
echo json_encode([$resultado, $resultado2]);
```

Por otro lado, ahora debes asignar las series de la siguiente manera:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "procesar.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { ANO: ANO, MES: MES },
  dataType: "json"
})
.done(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log(ANO);
  console.log(MES);
  /* Ahora "data" es una matriz de dos elementos, cada una contiene una serie: */
  chart.series[0].setData(data[0]);
  chart.series[1].setData(data[1]);
});
```